# About Print formated Datetime in linux shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell, date

After i type: date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" in linux shell i get the right result such as: 14-09-26 10:47:28.

However, when i want to get the result in a shell script, I get a error : "date: illegal time format", Why?

```
#!/bin/sh

STR='date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'

echo "`$STR`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with:

```
#!/bin/sh

STR='date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'

echo "`$STR`"
```

is that when the string is executed in the `echo` command, the `date` command sees three arguments:

```
date
+%y-%m-%d
%H:%M:%S
```

It is trying to interpret the `%H:%M:%S` as a date/time in the format:

```
[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]]
```

or:

```
mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]
```

or:

```
[MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

(the first from Mac OS X `date`, the second from POSIX, the third from GNU `date`).  In those, the pairs of letters represent components of the date to be set as the time.  Since the `%H:%M:%S` string contains no digits, it is an invalid date format.

How could you work around this?

It depends in part on whether `/bin/sh` is Bash, Korn shell, Dash, Bourne shell or some other shell.

The simplest solution should work in all but the oldest Bourne shells, and that is to create a function:

```
dt() { date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'; }
```

You can then use:

```
echo "$(dt)"
```

using the `$(…)` notation in preference to back-ticks.

Note that I decline to use `%y`; I remember the Y2K bug, even if you're too young to have been involved in the remediation work.

An alternative technique requires support for arrays (Bash, Korn shells, but not Dash or Bourne):

```
STR=( date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )

echo "$( "${STR[@]}" )"
```

or, more simply:

```
"${STR[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I use %y just as a example.

Comment: I can see you use `%y`; I'm strongly recommending that you use `%Y` because you're reinventing the Y2K bug and that was not a good thing when it happened.   However, it's your funeral, not mine.  Or, perhaps, you think it will be the funeral of the person after the person after you and you'll be long gone — I will be too, but I prefer to write resilient software that has a chance of lasting longer than me.

Answer (score 0):

Try excecuting at the assignment iteself.

```
 $ #!/bin/sh

   $ STR=`date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

   $ echo $STR
  14-09-26 11:40:06
```

Comment: You can execute commands within the shell and assign the results to a variable either by enclosing the command in **backtics** or by using the `$(command)` syntax. E.G. `STR=$(date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`. **Note:** `quotes` **ARE** proper within backtics or `$("$somevar_A" ... "$somevar_B")` and do not effect `quoting` **outside** the command execution expression.

Comment: Note that evaluating the date at the assignment to `STR` means that the same value will be printed each time the script does `echo $STR`.  If the intent is to produce different timestamps on each time the `echo` is done, then this doesn't help.  For a one-off timestamp, the script would simply execute `date` without capturing the output.  It is plausible that the command should be executed each time, not just the once (though I grant you the question doesn't say that).